# Google Webmaster Tools refusing to see my Structured Data

Tags: google-search-console, microdata

I've been unable to get Webmaster tools to see my sites structured data. It keeps reporting "We do not detect any structured data on your site".

You can inspect my html by visiting: http://www.cgtag.com

I can verify that my Schema.org data is formatted correctly using Yandex. It reports 50 objects on my home page.

http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml

On my home page in the `<head>` section I have this object.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"CollectionPage","description":"Everything Related To Computer Graphics, Visual Effects and 3D Animation","name":"cgTag | Everything Related To Computer Graphics, Visual Effects and 3D Animation","alternateName":"cgTag"}</script>
```

For each article shown on the home page, and inside each `<article>` tag. I have an object like this.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"Article","name":"TRANSFORMERS 4 Trailer 2","headline":"TRANSFORMERS 4 Trailer 2","description":"TRANSFORMERS 4 Trailer 2\nParamount Pictures has released the new trailer for Transformers: Age of Extinction, hitting theaters on June 27.\nTransformers: Age of Extinction is the fourth film in director Michael Bay\u00e2\u0080\u0099s global blockbuster franchise. Mark Wahlberg, Stanley Tucci, Li Bingbing, Kelsey Gr","url":"\/post\/10020\/transformers-4-trailer-2","datePublished":"2014-05-15T07:06:34-04:00","copyrightHolder":{"@type":"Organization","name":"CG Meet Up","url":"\/sources\/62\/cg-meet-up"},"Image":"http:\/\/s0.cgtag.com\/img\/post\/2014\/5\/15\/thumb-10020-12.jpg"}</script>
```

The only thing I can conclude. Is that Google is ignoring Schema.org data defined in `<script type="application/ld+json>` blocks.

This seems like an unlike answer, because it's well documented that defining microdata this way is allowed.

If I use the Google structure data inspector. It's not showing data for the articles.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cgtag.com

EDIT: It's been over a month now waiting for the data to appear.

Comment: "because it's well documented that defining microdata this way is allowed.": Note that you don’t use *Microdata* here, it’s JSON-LD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google won't pick up on any markup that isn't visible to users](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493?hl=en#hidden).  Because of this policy, they are unlikely to recognize any structured data that is in `<script>` tags.

> In general, Google won't display any content in rich snippets that is not visible to human user. Don't hide the content that you have marked up for rich snippets using techniques like `display:none`, `value-title`, or `css`. Google will ignore content that isn't visible to human users, so you should mark up the text that visitors will see on your web pages.
>
> Note that in a few limited circumstances, it can be useful to provide both a machine-readable and a human-readable version of your content. For example, because the text string `"Elvis's birthday"` is significant to a great many human readers, but less so to machines, Google provides a way to provide the date in a machine-readable form—`1935-01-08`—while still displaying the content in a human-friendly way. For more information, check the Help article for each product type.

Comment: This might apply for Rich Snippets, but there are other uses of Schema.org, e.g. Google recommends to use JSON-LD in a `script` element for [`MusicEvent` etc. on musical artist websites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4620133?hl=en).

Comment: This is no longer true for all structured data. Google is recommending use of JSON+LD now, which is distinct from the visible content.

Answer (score 0):

Google now [suggest using JSON+LD](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4620709?hl=en) for listing corporate contacts. However, validator support for it isn't very good.

You can check that your syntax is correct using the [Corporate Contacts Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/corporatecontacts) provided by Google. Unlike the Structured Data Testing Tool, this tool supports JSON+LD. HowerveGoogle suggests it will take up to a week for the changes to be updated. You can also test your syntax using the [Yandex Structured data validator](http://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml).